# how to know when uislider animation ends

Tags: iphone, animation, uislider

I'm using the setValue message of the UISlider class allowing animation, as follow:

```
[mySlider setValue :0.0 animated:YES]
```

I googled but found nothing on this: how to know when the animation (of the setValue) stops ?

Thanks

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from my machine at the moment so can't check the details, but what happens if you link the valueChanged action of the slider to something, does that get called before or after the animation is complete?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I linked the _UIControlEventValueChanged_ of the _UISlider_ to a method, but this is not called when the value changed through a _[myslider setValue :0];_. I seems the handler is called only when this change comes from a user change...SO I cannot know when the animation is done and the slider is back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UISlider like that to know when it start, changed or finished.

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderDragStart(_:)), for: .touchDown)

slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderDragEnd(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func sliderDragStart(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    print("slider drag start")
}

@objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    print("slider value changed")
}

@objc func sliderDragEnd(_ sender: UISlider)
{
    print("slider drag End")
}
```